# Cyberoam authenticated network only allows browsers to connect to internet, not any other application

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wireless-networking, authentication

I'm accessing my college network (which is protected via Cyberoam) via Wifi, and I need to authenticate to the network using my ID in the web browser. Once done, I can access internet with the browser (but, keeping the authentication tab opened).

But other web based apps in the computer can't access network (due to lack of authentication). For example, Windows Update is not working, chat clients can't connect (even on off days when social networking sites are allowed in the network).

Is there any way I can apply the authentication system-wide so that it works for every app installed? I'm looking for solution that works on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you asked the local computer tech support?

Comment: I guess that the network only allows HTTP and SSL ports (80 and 443) -- in that case you're out of luck. Does it work when using multiple browsers simultaneously?

Comment: slhck: Ya, every browser installed in the system works, condition is that the tab in which I authenticated cyberoam with my credentials must be kept open, as closing the tab also logs out from cyberoam.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't have much of a choice. Ask your local tech support, as @Zoredrache said. Get more information about what is actually permitted. Btw: You need to mention me with @, otherwise I won't get a notification.

Comment: @slhck: ya will contact the same, another thing I found that my friend's laptop has access to college wifi without any cyberoam authentication involved, nothing is specially configured in that system, but still it can connect right away.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to application and website filtering rules configured by Firewall Admin on your college network. In many schools and colleges such restrictions are recommended by management.

You can check with your IT support or Firewall Admin about this and if he can help you resolve this issue.